# Is there any wifi scanner GUI app for Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, gui, asus, scanner, tools

Using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop on my Asus Laptop ..is there any app by which i can who is usig my wifi and pinpoint there location on map ????

Comment: There are some wifi scanners, but not with anything like maps and locations. Does this answer your question? [Is there a tool like wifi analyzer for ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237777/is-there-a-tool-like-wifi-analyzer-for-ubuntu)

Comment: actually i need to pinpoint my wifi stealer , who is using my wifi without my authorisation

Comment: You can just change the password. There is no easy way to find who is connected without law enforcement privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that wifi technology allows you to get location info. All you can know is that there is a device that has registered with your wifi.

I am assuming that you have a wifi device in your laptop. Its a fair assumption, but hot a given. You could be connected via a wired connection to a router. If that were to be the case, nothing I can say would help you.

But you could use LinSSID (**sudo apt-get install linssid**) . Run it in privileged mode (ie, via: **sudo linssid**). It needs sudo because it goes to the device driver of your wifi device and puts it in to what is known as promiscuous mode. That way it can listen to any device that is out there and which your device can see. It has a graphical interface, so its pretty easy to understand.

One word of caution. I don't know for certain, because I have a wired interface that I am using, plus I have a wifi device that I generally don't use (it was free on the motherboard!). But if you are using the wifi as a general interface to the outside world, you may find that you lose connectivity when doing a scan. I can't be certain, and it may be device dependent, but it is a possibility.

Comment: i have a common dual band wifi router from local ISP from which all my family members r using...but when i scan thorugh FING (android app) it shows some unknown devices connected speacially to the 5G band of my router..Hence i need to pinpoint the device i heard it is possible todo so in internet hence asking.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you change the wifi password and then force the wifi router to reboot and clear its cache. That does mean changing the password on all your devices. 

From Ubuntu, you can do: 
sudo arp-scan --interface=enp9s0 --localnet

(Change the interface address to your own). That will run an ARP scan on your network, and it may give you some idea of what is connecting.

Comment: k will try that thnk u